# Regurgitating during exercise

Tags: cardio

So yesterday I did 55 minutes on the treadmill, the settings were 30 minutes at 9mph and 25 minutes at 8mph, all 55 minutes were done at 2% incline...
then I did some squats, nothing heavy, it was 50kg and I was doing them slow and keeping good form. I did 2 sets of 30 repetitions.

Then I went back on the treadmill to some HIIT, then thing is when I was running I kept throwing up a little in my mouth, it didn't stop for the 30 minutes I was doing HIIT, my settings were 15mph for 1 minute, walk for 1 minute, all at 2% incline.

Why was this happening? Is there a reason my body was throwing up all this stuff?

Comment: I experience this to a smaller degree when I drink too much during workouts. What did you eat/drink before and during your workouts?

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla nothing, I got home from work, got changed and went straight to the gym... although during my workouts I drink water, but only if my body starts asking, I don't drink it like a mad guy haha

Comment: @LarissaGodzilla sorry, the last time I would have eaten is 12:00pm which is when I have lunch. I usually eat after my workout, no snacking in between, only water, especially with this warm weather we are having :D

Comment: This [U.ofV. article](http://uvahealth.com/services/digestive-health/conditions-and-treatments/gastroesophageal-reflux-disease-gerd-heartburn) states that one of the causes of reflux is from "exercising immediately after eating (especially jogging or strenuous activity)". But I found this article about [HIIT and acid reflux](http://www.scarysymptoms.com/2014/03/can-hiit-trigger-acid-reflux.html) that suggests having a "small amount of food" before ex. (However I don't know anything about the validity of the site's info.)  I do know that "this stuff" is acidic and not good for your esophagus.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You overtrained.

Is your body conditioned for such exercise?

Personally, with my 2 years of experience in bodybuilding, I find such workout far too stressful. A few guidelines you should follow:

- Never combine squats, cardio and HIIT in one workout.You can do them in one day (squats in the morning and cardio in the evening), but never in one workout.
- Don't exercise more than 1 hour unless you have the needed condition of your body.
- No FOOD at least an hour before exercise.

  If you are taking any supplements such as Yohimbine or anything that can upset your stomach - make sure you've had a meal in the last 2-3 hours. If you are taking ANY supplements, please check their expiration date.

  I hope I was helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Why shouldn't I combine squats with cardio? I have the energy...

Comment: This is not a reason to keep training. If I take enough caffeine/ taurine / propionate I'll have the energy too,but my body - not really. When your body is undergoing extreme stress, it starts to dehydrate. If you lift heavy, regurgiating is normal because your body gets extremely stressed out. Just look up for videos of people doing heavy exercises such as deadlift and squat, and fainting/regurgitating afterwards. This is a normal side effect of stress on your body. Don't do it unless it is really necessary.

Comment: Why no exercise longer than 1 hour, and why no food for an hour before? These are highly individual recommendations.

Comment: @JohnP, to answer your question on the 1h rule (this needn't apply to long distance, but it does for high intensity exercise): after 1h of training the level of testosterone has peaked and starts to decline in favor of a cortisol-to-testosterone ratio. Im not up to date on how it relates to long distance though.

Comment: @DarkoSarovic - Thanks! I figured there had to be a rationale behind it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you were regurgitating slightly is mostly because of the slow squats. As you exercise, especially with exercises that require tight abdominal muscles, you increase the pressure in the abdomen. Slow squats will do this, especially after an hour of running (which also engages the muscles in the abdominal area).

This has the effect of decreasing the volume of space available for the internal organs, which can start pushing items in the stomach in various directions until you stop compressing the area.

While no food may be a recommendation, a lot of items will empty out of the stomach within an hour, some foods in much less time, so you will need to determine what and how soon before exercise you can eat.

Comment: LOL at the *available for the internal organs, which can start pushing items in the stomach in various directions.*

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD - There was a study I found on horses that when they were running, it reduced their stomach volume by close to 80%. :)